# How to get decrypted content from a pfx certificate

Tags: certificates

I am developing ERP software. One of the features that I am implementing is the issuance of invoices, which is something related to the federal revenue of my country.

In the documentation says that I need an A1 or A3 certificate to sign the note, the problem that does not I find information about this type of certificate even though I have one in hand, this is a bit of a signed note example:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                <Reference URI="#NFe32180305570714000825550010033494951101092824">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    <DigestValue>v+9yjukhW8UMdC5Sj3DpS5mPy5I=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>piLLX1Xk3gsp7MVK4OtKde1S2yio3SagyRTCpI/Sklcy2JC5yOFr5tOuLx4deA1W9WtWfh7QJLxcHOR4ySu8Iz+9VW3exJpCn+eyymeNbM5ONNZD5eFNIoAHEwrA7wr08YTYRrFFKyhuauHhAusei4nYGo6LhlE9iVabUKO6eIfKEGEbfqivzj0kSdVsUBhIEQ1PxbbTlSXvTPZ8qsV3JNGGLggc5hXCApMMrbmdoGiwm6/M5v4gVSNuhwLquUvFPWSl9wphRQI4RXNCehW6357xRqrAFAHRgePqg3MJd8mpZvNqfHz8iboqYkAhCUqGzQHInkb9o9rkX9Rya1SrJw==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
```

Comment: In what documentation? What note?

Comment: this http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=URCYvjVMIzI=